# Doing something with the numeric keypad

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I, like most people, don't use the numeric keypad on my keyboard much and they seem to me to be a complete waste of otherwise perfectly good eighteen keys.

I was wondering if there was something cool that could be done with them - I've heard of some people controlling their mouse pointer using the 2, 4, 6 and 8 keys, but that does seem very practical to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your OS and/or Window Manager? that'd help in giving us instructions on the how-to...

Comment: I use StumpWM. The idea is more important - I'll figure out a way to actually implement one way or other. :)

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 4):

*Low tech solution*:

Remove the keys (easy with a pencil) so the key won't exceed the border, then you could glue a piece of wood over it and get a cup holder.

Comment: Or wire a usb cup warmer into it. Hot drinks within reach at all times

Answer (score 1):

I use my keypad keys for adding, subtracting, multiplication, division, numerical data entry, etc. Now I'm going to use my CTRL, SHIFT, and W keys together to try and figure out what this has to do with programming...

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom keyboard layout? 
Real languages often have special characters you could put there.
Alternately if you use APL you could put their 'unique' characters in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using AutoHotKey http://www.autohotkey.com/, and setting up some hotkeys for common tasks that you perform, for example:**

- Opening my computer
- Opening your data folders
- Opening web browser
- Copying as plain text
- Sleeping the computer
- Etc.